# ALSA broken; dummy output or HDMI output, alsa won't reload

Tags: 20.04, sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Intel Cannon Lake sound card. HDMI output isn't working, actually; it says it is working but when I plug HDMI in, nothing happens. ALSA force-reload has to be quit with ctrl c, it hangs at

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer
```

At startup `[   72.483004] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d80` displays around 10-11 times.

Reinstalled pulseaudio, didn't work.

dmesg displays

```
[   61.071532] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead
[   61.071557] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   61.071740] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[   61.334100] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=3 (0x15/0x1b/0x17/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   61.334102] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   61.334104] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   61.334104] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   61.334105] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    dig-out=0x1e/0x0
[   61.334106] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   61.334108] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x18
[   61.334109] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
[   61.347120] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: autoconfig for Generic: line_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[   61.347121] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   61.347122] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    hp_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   61.347122] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   61.347123] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    dig-out=0x3/0x0
[   61.347123] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2:    inputs:
[   63.386851] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x20270503
[   64.390876] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   65.398853] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   66.402942] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   68.451032] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   69.458985] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   70.467005] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   71.470859] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d81
[   72.483004] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d80
[   74.490997] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   75.494897] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   76.507008] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   78.555011] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   79.558892] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   80.562942] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   82.602984] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   83.610988] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   84.623029] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   86.670976] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   87.682963] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   88.690866] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   90.734960] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   91.743022] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   92.746941] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   94.786985] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   95.795042] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[   96.798901] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[   98.842943] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[   99.847008] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[  100.850960] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  102.890987] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270503
[  103.902885] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370503
[  104.910949] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  125.951004] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  126.954990] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  127.959032] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  128.963013] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  130.003012] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  131.007019] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  132.018971] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  133.023022] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  134.055034] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  135.059002] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  136.067033] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  137.071020] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  138.103033] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  139.107027] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  140.111041] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  141.119036] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  142.151039] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  143.155054] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  144.159027] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  145.163023] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  146.195038] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  147.199034] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  148.207024] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  149.219037] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  150.254949] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  151.259025] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  152.267019] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  153.271018] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  154.307030] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  155.319007] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  156.326986] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  157.335028] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  158.367026] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  159.370960] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  160.386906] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  161.399036] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  162.431035] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20170500
[  163.435034] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270500
[  164.439033] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370500
[  165.447050] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x201f0500
[  166.478886] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370740
[  167.486999] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20370740
[  168.491003] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d80
[  168.491011] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -11
[  169.495002] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d80
[  169.495009] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -11
[  170.499006] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x203f0900
[  171.619029] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, resetting bus: last cmd=0x20270d81
[  172.622898] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x202a0000
[  173.279227] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[  173.279391] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[  212.415385] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  212.415549] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  653.963248] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[  653.963390] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 2649.279267] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 2649.279426] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 2966.667289] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 2966.667464] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 5579.527369] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 5579.527532] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 9397.551410] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 9397.551871] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 9397.582897] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[ 9397.583064] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[ 9399.415580] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 9399.415736] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 9554.690790] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(OE) nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) nvidia(POE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek mei_hdcp intel_rapl_msr snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio iwlmvm snd_hda_intel intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp rtsx_usb_ms mac80211 coretemp libarc4 memstick snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core iwlwifi snd_hwdep snd_pcm btusb kvm_intel kvm snd_seq_midi i915 btrtl snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq btbcm btintel snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel bluetooth snd soundcore ecdh_generic crypto_simd msi_wmi cryptd sparse_keymap glue_helper ecc rapl
[ 9557.324023] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 9557.324189] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[ 9557.367291] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[ 9557.367456] snd_hda_codec_generic hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
```

Comment: Some users report that moving to pipewire can fix these problems.  Is there a reason you need to use pulse?

Comment: I tried pipewire; it didn't work either. Then I switched back to pulseaudio and now the speakers are outputting something, though only static. It outputs "Built-in Audio Analog Surround" through the speakers(!), and I can't select anything else.

Comment: `snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead`  Here search for this I mean this dmic part.  `grep -r dmic /etc/modprobe.d/`

Comment: @nobody grep -r dmic /etc/modprobe.d/
 gives output /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf:options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

Comment: `sudo nano /etec/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`  and change  `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0` to `#options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0 ` So the system ignores it and reboot.

Comment: Oh error in my previous comment. `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` of course.